# Jquery refresh page after countdown hits 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, countdown

I am using Keith Wood Jquery Countdown Timer (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) and I wanted to make it so that when the timer hits 0 the page would refresh. unfortunately I couldn't make this happen.. Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
        var now = new Date($.now());
        var austDay = new Date();
        austDay = new Date(//php stuff to get the date from the database..);
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay, format: 'DHMS'});
        if (austDay <= now) {
            location.reload();
        }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation that *you* linked to, you can specify an `onExpiry` callback for when the countdown gets to zero. You then supply a function that can do whatever you like at that moment:

```
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
    until: austDay,
    format: 'DHMS',
    onExpiry: function() { location.reload(); }
});
```

(I haven't tested the above code, but it seems pretty clear in [the doco](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html).)

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thanks a bunch, I should read more the next time. :P

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#onExpiry)

> **onExpiry**: A callback function that is invoked when the countdown
>   reaches zero. Within the function this refers to the division that
>   holds the widget. No parameters are passed in. Use the expiryText or
>   expiryUrl settings for basic functionality on expiry.

```
$(selector).countdown({
    until: liftoffTime, onExpiry: liftOff});

function liftOff() {
    alert('We have lift off!');
}
```